# Swift array basics

Tags: swift

Gives an Index out of range eror.
Is there a syntax error or logic ?

```
func generateGameBoard()->([Int]){
        var gboard =  [Int]();
        var i : Int = 0;
        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
            gboard[i]=1;
        }
        return gboard;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var gboard =  [Int](); // you are creating an empty array here.
```

you need to append value in array
like

```
gboard.append(1) instead of   gboard[i]=1;
```

and c style for loop and ++ opeartor will not use in next versions of swift.

Answer (score 1):

Dont you notice error in your code. You create an empty array and then ask index for 0 ..< 8 which is invalid. You should really use **count** to iterate over the contents.

```
   func generateGameBoard()->([Int]){
        var gboard =  [Int]();
        for i in 0 ..< gboard.count {
            gboard[i]=1;
        }
        return gboard;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also get ready for swift 3 and update the for loop part. It won't compile as it stand now in swift 3. You have to change it to:
for i in 0..<8 {
}